# What is difference between identity server and identity provider?

Tags: oauth, saml, identity, federation, scim

I don't understand the difference between identity server and an identity provider. Are they same?
Can an identity server act as an identity provider for a cross-domain app.

Comment: What do you mean with `identity server` term?

Answer (score 7):

In this world of identity, there are a lot of different terms. Colloquially, they mean the same or very similar things, so your confusion is justifiable. There are nuanced differences though:

**Identity Provider (IdP)**:

1. A software component that authenticates and issues a token representing a user or other entity.
2. An organization or business that is responsible for the digital identity of a user or other entity.

**Identity Server**:
A server software component (in the client/server sense of the word) that authenticates and issues tokens that represent a user or other entity.

**OpenID Connect Provider (OP)**:
An identity server or service that supports the OpenID Connect protocol, and, thus, issues identity tokens to client application (which is referred to as a Relying Party, RP). Commonly called an IdP.

**SAML Identity Provider**:
An identity server or service that supports the SAML protocol. Commonly called an IdP.

**Authorization Server (AS)**:
A server (in the client/server sense of the word) that issues access tokens according to the OAuth protocol.

**Identity Service**:
A Web service or platform that authenticates and issues tokens that represent a user or other entity. Analogous to an identity server except that it is provided using a Software as a Service (SaaS) delivery model as opposed to software delivered. This is commonly referred to as Identity as a Service (IDaaS).

Comment: So... A server application that authenticates and issues tokens is an Identity Server, and is also can be called an Identity Provider?